# onclick i want to get the name of the JPanel that is present on the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, mouselistener

Below is what im trying to implement but its giving error on the line mentioned ; this is because the function doesnot get which Component.getName()  is of ...
    String name=new String();

```
                mntmOneToOne.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
               {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0)
                    {
                        String name=new String();
                        int count = arg0.getClickCount();
                        if (count == 1)
                        {
                          Component panel = (Component) arg0.getSource();   


                          System.out.println(panel.getName());
                        }

                    }
                 });
```

Comment: `"below Line is showing error as it doesnot know which panel is it about ..."` -- neither do we. Which panel is it all about? The one clicked on? If so, then call `getSource()` on the MouseEvent object. If not, then please fill us in with what you may be talking about. Please tell the details of your problem.

Comment: I have 2 3 panels having a specific name; on a JFrame ok... now my problem is when i click on panel i want to print its name on the console which i have assigned to it in the constructor by panelx.setName(text)  .

Comment: @alex23 : no!! System.out.println(panel.getName());   is not printing the name on console.. check the edited version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the clicked object via your MouseEvent's `getSource()` method. Then call its `getName()` method.

```
mntmOneToOne.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
     @Override
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
         int count = mouseEvent.getClickCount();
         if (count == 1) {
           Component panel = (Component)mouseEvent.getSource();
           name = panel.getName(); 
         }
     }
});
```

Comment: name is not printing on console .. please check the edited version which i have implemented

Comment: @Asdakamessoy: of course it's not printing in console. You need to have a println for that.

Comment: i added System.out.println(panel.getName());  ...  still no output

Comment: @Asdakamessoy: then you have an error elsewhere in code you're not showing us, such as not adding the MouseListener to the correct component, or who knows what? You should be creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 1):

See this example :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

    public class PanelTest extends JFrame {
        List<JPanel> panels;
        public PanelTest(){
            panels = new ArrayList<>();
            setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));
            Color [] color = {Color.white,Color.black,Color.blue,Color.red,Color.orange,Color.gray};
            for(int i = 0 ; i < 6;i++)
            {
                panels.add(new JPanel());
                panels.get(i).setName("Panel "+i);
                panels.get(i).addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ev){
                                        //JPanel p = (JPanel)ev.getSource();
                        System.out.println(((JPanel)ev.getSource()).getName());
                        }
                    });
                panels.get(i).setBackground(color[i]);
                getContentPane().add(panels.get(i));
            }
            setVisible(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
            setSize(400,400);
        }

        public static void main(String...args){
            new PanelTest();
            }

    }
```