# want to create a Selection mode and turn it off after clicking 2 JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, clicklistener

```
     mntmOneToOne.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
          @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0)
            {
                    String name=new String();
                int count = arg0.getClickCount();
  // selecting 1st panel
                    if (count == 1)
                    {
                        JPanel panel = (JPanel) arg0.getSource();   

                        //   name = panel.getName();    

                        System.out.println(panel.getName());

                     }

// selecting the 2nd panel
            if (count == 1)
            {
                   JPanel panel = (JPanel) arg0.getSource();    

                   //   name = panel.getName(); 

                  System.out.println(panel.getName());

           }


            }
     });
```

i want to create a mode on clicking mntmOnetoOne button ; in this mode any two panels which has been  clicked  among 5 panels on the JFrame, will show its(JPanel's) name on Console . After the user has clicked any two panels this mode automatically turns off.

Comment: or ther are two users with the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16362625/714968), or one user with two ID with the same question

Answer (score 1):

[Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html)s (with [AbstractAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractAction.html)) allow you to do what you want. The have an "enabled" property that you can set. See the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).

Comment: its a check box ! i want to do this via button

Comment: @Asd: Igor is not talking about check box or buttons but the Actions that underlie their functionality, and his advice is good. 1+. But your question is confusing in that you mention clicking on "button" and on "panels". Which is it?

Comment: mode turns on via button "mntmOneToOne" is that button !! and after clicking that button user needs to click 2 JPanels and onclick JPanel's names will be shown on the console..P.s. these 2 panels are among the 5 JPanels present on the JFrame already

Comment: @Asd: You can use Actions with JButton, JCheckBox and JRadioButton, there's no difference. When you implement the AbstractAction, you add a method to increase the counter and disable the Action.